# Search how many characters are in a C string

Tags: count, character, c-strings

My task is to count how many characters are in a C string. The input is provided by a test driver that I don't have access to but my function is supposed to access the data and determine how many characters range from a-z and A-Z but my program keeps failing and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
int countLetters(char * const line)
{
    char index = *line;
    int count;

   while(!index)
    {
        if (index >= 'a' && index <= 'z')
            count++;

        if (index >= 'A' && index <= 'Z')
            count++;
    }
    return count;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int countLetters(char * const line)
{
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while(line[index])
    {
        if (line[index] >= 'a' && line[index] <= 'z')
            count++;

        if (line[index] >= 'A' && line[index] <= 'Z')
            count++;

        index++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here's what you did wrong
**First:** You assign your char index = *line;
making your index the first character in the string, which is wrong, because index suppose to represent position, not a character
**Second:** You didnt provide any mechanism to increase the index in other to loop the string
**Third:** You didnt initialize your count variable

> Note: `line[index]` is the same as `*(line + index)`
>   Your `line` is a pointer which point to the first character in the string
>   So `line + index` is a pointer that point to the index-nth character in the string
>   By prefix a pointer with a * you're saying that i want to know the content that this pointer point to

Comment: > Try initialize count = 0 before you increment it

Tried that and the difference was instead of thousands of hits I got 0 returned. I'm not sure if the problem is coming from the program missing the NULL character or if the parameters in my if statements are wrong. Most times my return value is in the thousands when it should be ~50

Comment: You need to somehow increase your index each loop

Comment: OK so perfect, it's working but for some reason it's -1 off every time. I changed `code`while(line(index++) + 1])`code` which fixed it but I don't fully understand why that's happening.

Comment: I updated the code, you should try that version, it was my mistake to increase the index before checking for character

Comment: Gotcha, I was over thinking that. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: index++ do 2 things, first it make a copy of index, increase the index, and return the copy version.
Putting line[index++] in a while loop check if the character at the index position is not '/0' eol character and increase the index afterward